# Hiding then showing HTML based off select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show html content based off a select value. When anything other than `cables` is selected I want to show `Manufacturer` and `Model` but when cables is selected I want to not show those two inputs. I want to so that I can select `cables` then when I select `aps` that it will bring those two fields back. What is the best/most proper method of doing this? Code snippet to show what I am getting. I removed a lot of the options for simplicity's sake.

```js
var sel=document.getElementById("type");
var manufacturer=document.getElementById("manufacturer");
var model=document.getElementById("model");
var typeInputs=document.getElementById("typeInputs");
var aps = '<h1>aps</h1>';
var cables = '<h1>cables</h1>';

function typePicker(){
if(sel.value=="aps"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=aps;
}

if(sel.value=="cables"){
  manufacturer.innerHTML= "";
  model.innerHTML= "";
  typeInputs.innerHTML=cables;
}
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="manufacturer">
  <label for="manufacturer"  class="control-label">Manufacturer</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Manufacturer" name="manufacturer" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
                            
<div class="form-group" id="model">
  <label for="model" class="control-label">Model Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" name="model" placeholder="Model Name">
</div>
                   
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Type of Asset" name="type" data-live-search="true" id="type" onchange="typePicker()">
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <option value="aps">Access Point</option>
    <option value="cables">Cable</option>
    <option value="desktops">Desktop</option>
  </select>
</div>
                            
<div class="form-group" id="typeInputs">
                                
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for hide:

```
_element.style.display = 'none';
```

for show:

```
_element.style.display = 'block';
```

```js
var sel=document.getElementById("type");
var manufacturer=document.getElementById("manufacturer");
var model=document.getElementById("model");
var typeInputs=document.getElementById("typeInputs");
var aps = '<h1>aps</h1>';
var cables = '<h1>cables</h1>';

function typePicker(){
if(sel.value=="aps"){
  typeInputs.innerHTML=aps;
}

if(sel.value=="cables"){
  manufacturer.style.display = 'none';
  model.style.display = 'none';
  typeInputs.innerHTML=cables;
}else{
  manufacturer.style.display = 'block';
  model.style.display = 'block';
}
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="manufacturer">
  <label for="manufacturer"  class="control-label">Manufacturer</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Manufacturer" name="manufacturer" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
                            
<div class="form-group" id="model">
  <label for="model" class="control-label">Model Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" name="model" placeholder="Model Name">
</div>
                   
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Type of Asset" name="type" data-live-search="true" id="type" onchange="typePicker()">
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <option value="aps">Access Point</option>
    <option value="cables">Cable</option>
    <option value="desktops">Desktop</option>
  </select>
</div>
                            
<div class="form-group" id="typeInputs">
                                
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick reply/ answer and the code snippet of it working. Much appreciated. I will try to implement this and see if I can get it to work for me.